# What is the difference between ?int $number and int $number = null?

Tags: php

Given this explanation

> Nullable types: Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively.
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

The following code :

```php
public function test(?int $var) {

}
```

Means that `test()` can be called with `$var` either as `int` or as `null`.

And the following code :

```php
public function test(int $var = null) {

}
```

Means that `test()` can be called with `$var` either as `int` or as `null` as well.

What are the differences between those two methods ? Is any of these more performant than the other?

Comment: The functional difference is that the second one makes the parameter optional, i.e.g you can call `test()` whereas with the first, the parameter is still required, but can be null. Performance wise, I doubt there's anything in it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between the two language features being discussed here, that is, [type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) and [default argument values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

The first function is only using type declarations, this means that the input argument ***has*** to be of the type `int` or `NULL`.

The second function is using both type declarations and default argument values, this means that the argument ***has*** to be of the type `int` or `NULL` ***but*** if omitted it will default to `NULL`.

Take your first function, if you simply called `test()` without passing anything to it, you'd get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function test() [...]

which is correct as the function expects either `int` or `NULL` but got neither whereas for the second, as you have defined the argument with a default value, it would run without errors.

**Code**

```
function test(?int $var) {
  var_dump($var);
}

function test2(int $var = null) {
  var_dump($var);
}

test(1); // fine
test(); // error
test2(1); // fine
test2(); // fine
```

As far as performance goes, the difference is probably negligible, nothing significant enough that would be a cause for concern.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/PoisedRosyDeletions)

Answer (score 14):

If the language were designed today, `int $var = null` would probably be an error, and should really be written `?int $var = null`. The two parts mean different things:

- The `?` indicates that `null` is a valid value for that parameter.
- The `= null` indicates that `null` is the default if the parameter is not passed.

However, before the `?type` syntax was introduced, there was a special case in the language: if `null` is given as the default for a parameter, then it is legal to pass `null` to that parameter, even if the type declaration would otherwise prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is how you can call the function:

```
// public function test(?int $var)
$foo->test("x");    // does not work (Argument 1 passed to Foo::test() must be of the type int or null, string given)
$foo->test(123);    // works
$foo->test(null);   // works
$foo->test();       // does not work (Too few arguments to function Foo::test(), 0 passed)

// public function test(int $var = null)
$foo->test("x");    // does not work (Argument 1 passed to Foo::test() must be of the type int or null, string given)
$foo->test(123);    // works
$foo->test(null);   // works
$foo->test();       // works
```

The difference is that you cannot call the function as `->test()` using the first syntax.